# How to update parse User ojbect. I want to update longitude and latitude after every 10 seconds

Tags: android, android-studio, parse-platform

I have wrote a code that gives me new values of longitude and latitude. I want to store them in ParseUser's object user. user already have two columns latitude and longitude. I am trying to update these value like this. Check code. am i doing right? NOTE i am using GooglePlay Services for location updates

```
   if(mRequestingLocationUpdates){
            ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            user.put("Latitude",lattitude);
            user.put("Longitude",longitude);
            user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    if(e != null){

                    }else
                    {

                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do it is implementing the LocationListener.

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener
```

Create all you need on your OnCreate

```
        mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.mapView);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mapView.onResume();

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        googleMap = mapView.getMap();
        googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
```

Then use the "onLocationChanged"

```
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        // Getting latitude of the current location
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();

        // Getting longitude of the current location
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();

        // Creating a LatLng object for the current location
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

        MarkerOptions mp = new MarkerOptions();

        mp.position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));

        mp.title("My Location");
        mp.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher));

        googleMap.addMarker(mp);

        // Showing the current location in Google Map
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

        // Zoom in the Google Map
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
```

This'll update the location every time the user moves a little. It's better than checking every 10 sec and killing the battery life.

Comment: how to send new longitude and latitude to parse.com

Comment: when user is logined.

Comment: Every time

if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }

triggers... then you can send the data.

Comment: Actually that is where i am having problem it is not changing longitude and latitude in database. Name of my table is user and it has field longitude for longitude and latitude for latitude. give me a example code wise

Comment: The parse tutorials looks perfect https://parse.com/docs/android/guide You'll have to trigger your saveInBackground every time onLocationChanged is called and catch that data (latitude and longitude) to user.put("Latitude",latitude); user.put("Longitude",longitude);  to get the new values and send them correctly.

Comment: And how to add mapview widge since there isn't any such in android studio

Comment: Like this: <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" /> (set width and height as you wish)